# mathematical operations on two different datatypes

Tags: c

I am using two different datatypes and doing the calculation by mathematical operators.

```
 int x = 1;
 double y = 2;
 int z;
 z = x*y;
 printf("Result %d\n", z);
```

Will it be Ok??

Comment: Try it. What happens? Make sure to enable all warnings.

Comment: results are fine.. not worried much about precision..

Comment: So .. then, what's the issue? :-/

Comment: What you want to know/learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll lose precision (probably getting a warning) if the value has a fractional part. It will be truncated.

Example:

```
const float PI = 3.14;
int notPi = PI;
```

`notPi` will be truncated to `3`

Comment: Ok. i am fine with precision loss.. else will it affect anything?

Comment: @Vishwadeep nothing will affect here

Comment: If you're okay with precision loss, cast it as an `int` to remove warning and you're good to go.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey hmmm i was looking for casting only.. thanks now i am good to go..